# can xlwings run excel in the background?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I run a Python XLWings code where multiple Excel files are called sequentially. Although the code closes each Excel after dealing with it (and no more than 1 excel is open at any given moment), the process becomes increasingly slow. Memory tests show that residual processes remain after closing excel files.

Is there a smoother way to do this? Can maybe XLWings call these Excel files in background mode, without spending time and memory on loading the interface?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, `xlwings` does also allow you to keep the Excel application invisibly in the background. For this you must use an [`xlwings.App`](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.App) object with input parameter `visible=False`.

Simple example:

```
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App(visible=False)
book = app.books[0]
sheet = book.sheets[0]

sheet.range('A1').value = 73913

book.save('book.xlsx')
app.kill()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just saw more details on the documentation.